# Failed to install MikTeX

Tags: miktex, tex-core

Today, I tried to install the current MikTeX version (basic-miktex-23.10-x64.exe, published on 10/06/2023), which was downloaded from the MikTeX homepage. Unfortunately, I get the following bizarre error message:

[image: Screenshot]

I am working on a Lenovo Yoga Book 9i with Microsoft Windows Home 11, Version 10.0.22621.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: No, I didn't used the Microsoft store at all. ;-) Just made the download via the MikTeX homepage.

Comment: Yes, I misread it sorry ;). Does it have to be MiKTeX? You could use TeXLive instead and download it directly from the [webpage](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html). Or yu have to find out which app is missing.

Comment: I fear, yes. I use MikTeX since decades and my workflow is really adapted to that TeX distribution. :-)

Comment: **Exactly** what did you do when you got that messasge? It sounds like you were trying to open a file that Windows does not knwo what to do with.

Comment: Can you find out which App is missing? It doesn't read like an error message, more like a missing setup.

Comment: After clicking on "Ja" (i.e., "yes"), I simply get the message that such an app does not exist in the store.

Comment: Well, it is just an executable file ...

Comment: Again, eaxtly what did you do here? Where are we in the process of installing MikTeX. did you just download an exe from MikTeX and is trying to run it? Please remember that we are not standing next to you, so we do not know what **exactly** you are doing. Thus please be specific.

Comment: @GabrielFrahm, unless MikTex people are around here I suggest to turn to their support page: https://miktex.org/support . And probably your question is a bit out of scope for this place. The closing votes will show, soon.

Comment: I normally don't use Windows or MikTeX. But gave it a try. For me it was blocked by Windows Defender since it is not signed. Not sure how to "run anyway" in Win11.

Comment: 1. I have downloaded the exe from the MikTeX homepage.
2. I double-clicked on the exe file.
3. Then, the error message ocurred.

Comment: I'm also not a regular Windows user, but that sounds like something very fundamental isn't set up correctly. Running an `.exe` file should normally be no problem for the system. That might be more of a problem for a Windows community or maybe superuser.se, at least, it is not a TeX related problem.

Comment: Now I at last know what to do in the Win11 version I have on my test laptop. You need to tell windows it is allowed to run this programme from an unknown vendor. Right click > Properties. At the very bottom, there might be an interface to "unlock" the exe file. Then I can at last start the installer om my system.

Comment: This hint has solved the problem: "Right click > Properties. At the very bottom, there might be an interface to "unlock" the exe file." Great! Thanks a lot ... ;-)

Comment: @daleif Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 1):

The error the OP shows in their image is very strange.

On my test Win11, which is in English, I got a message that Windows defender/Screen would not run this programme as it came from an untrusted source.

In Win10 there would be an option to run the programme anyway. In Win11 this is much more hidden.

1. Right click on the `exe`
2. Choose `Properties`
3. At the bottom of the popup where will be a text about whether you want to unblock/unlock this file, with a check box next to it.
4. Check the box and you should be able to run the `exe`.

As always, do not do this unless you really trust the supplier of the `exe` file.

Bonus shout out to my local IT department about the hint to `run anyway` in Win11.